# How to remove the Ray effect when removing an object from a scene with THREE.js?

Tags: html, webgl, three.js

```
function checkHit(bullet, b){

                for(var i = collidableMeshList.length-1 ; i>=0; i--){
                var collideMesh = collidableMeshList[i];
                var v = collideMesh.geometry.vertices[0];
            var c = collideMesh.position;
            var x = Math.abs(v.x), z = Math.abs(v.z);
                if(bullet.x < c.x + x && bullet.x > c.x - x && bullet.z < c.z + z && bullet.z > c.z - z){

                scene.remove(b); // Removing Bullet After Hitting
                 scene.remove(collideMesh); // Removing After hit By Bullet
                 delete collidableMeshList[index]; // deleting that Index on which the Mesh is Placed
                return true;
                }
                }

                return false;
            }
```

I want to ask that how to remove the Ray effect or object effect from that deleted and removed place as i am not able to move my car from the place even if I delete the object or remove it from the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by:

```
 renderer.deallocateObject( obj );
```

or
     obj.deallocate();

This will completely erase the object. 
Please read this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2621
Cheers